# I'm trying to print a label using crystalreport in visual studio 2017 from a database set

Tags: c#, database, printing, visual-studio-2017, crystal-reports

I'm trying to create a label application in Visual Studio 2017 that uses a database set for storing data and same time print those data in the form of labels.

However, I'm having trouble getting data from the database to the label. For example, when I click on the "Print" button, it prompts you to enter your P.O number, and then click OK; it then shows a window with the names of all the fields but no data.

Here is my C# for the "Print" button:

```
 private void print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dtd = new DataTable();

        dtd.Columns.Add("Your P.O #", typeof(string));
        dtd.Columns.Add("Your Job #", typeof(string));
        dtd.Columns.Add("Title", typeof(string));
        dtd.Columns.Add("Quantity in the Box", typeof(string));
        dtd.Columns.Add("Box", typeof(string));
        dtd.Columns.Add("of", typeof(string));

        foreach (DataGridViewRow dtgv in dtgv.Rows)
        {
            dtd.Rows.Add(dtgv.Cells[1].Value, dtgv.Cells[2].Value, dtgv.Cells[3].Value, dtgv.Cells[4].Value, dtgv.Cells[5].Value, dtgv.Cells[6].Value);
            

        }

            ds.Tables.Add(dtd);
            ds.WriteXmlSchema("sticker.mdf");

        prtsticker fm = new prtsticker();
        stickerprint cr = new stickerprint();

        cr.SetDataSource(ds);
        fm.Show();





    }
```

Comment: Do you connect to the database? I don't seem to see the database connection statement. Please show your form interface and space name, you need to provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here.

Comment: yes, I connect the crystal report to the database using the wizard during the creation of crystal report.